# BAT script, how to write?

Tags: batch-file, dosbox

I have always repeat the same entries in Dosbox command-prompt (I always have to run dosbox and enter this commands one after another):

```
mount c C:\PROGRA~1\OPAL
c:
OPAL
LIB
```

Before entering LIB it asks me something, I can't even see what (the output is in the wrong charset). Is there a way for me to automatize this process?

Comment: You put the commands in a bat file and Dosbox has a method to run the bat file on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your file path was shown that you're on Windows.

**For Windows Case:**

> The user profile folder or Home Folder is a place where DOSBox will
>   look for the Dosbox.conf file for the user that executes dosbox.exe.
>   The location of this folder varies depending on the host Operating
>   System.
>
> It appears that ..
>
> Start > All Programs > DOSBox > Configuration > Edit Configuration

- Find this part

> ```
> [autoexec]
> # Lines in this section will be run at startup.
> # You can put your MOUNT lines here.
> ```

- It appears in the file 'Dosbox.conf'.

Then you can add your part there after that part like this

> ```
> [autoexec]
> # Lines in this section will be run at startup.
> # You can put your MOUNT lines here.
>
> mount c C:\PROGRA~1\OPAL
> c:
> OPAL
> LIB
> ```

Save then restart the DOSBox.

/////

**For Mac Case:**

You can go to the file

> DOSBox 0.74 Preferences

It's in the path

> ~/Library/Preferences/

It suppose to be OSX with DOSBox 0.74 the lastest version now. Then, you can edit it with vi like this

> sudo vi ~/Library/Preferences/DOSBox 0.74 Preferences

Or any way to edit it by TextEdit.

- Find the same  part

> **[autoexec]**

Then add it with your own configuration or something like these.

> ```
> mount c ~/Documents/_DOSAP_/
> c:
> dir
> ```

Then, restart the DOSBox.
That's all.

(Ref : http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf and http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/User_profile_folder)

Comment: Great. I still have to enter "LIB", but the rest done automatically, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use SET Commands..

```
Set Drv = C:\
Set Subdir = Windows\
Set Subdir2 = System32

Cd %Drv%%Subdir%%SubDir2%
```

If you want to interact with the Batch file..  Bill Stewart has a set tool that can help..

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html